# Compare the rank of the module $M$ over the different rings $O_K$ and $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ with $O_K$ its the ring of integers. Consider a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra $A$ such that $|A|<\infty$.

Consider a module $M$ over the ring $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ and assume $M$ is $A$-flat as well. So $M$ is a module over $O_K$ also.

My question is really about the ranks of $M$ over the different $3$ rings: More clearly, let

\begin{align}
r_1&:=\text{rank}_{O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A}(M), \\ r_2&:=\text{rank}_{O_K}(M), \\r_3&:=\text{rank}_{ A}(M)
\end{align}
I want to understand relation between the ranks $r_1,~r_2,~r_3$  of the module $M$ over the rings $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$, $O_K $ and $A$ respectively.

$(1)$ What is the relation among $r_1,~r_2,~r_3$ ?

$(2)$ Is $r_1=r_2=r_3$ or $r_1=r_3$ or $r_1=r_2$ ?

Clearly $O_K$ being an integral domain, the $O_K$-rank of $M$ is equal to the $K$-vector space dimension of $(K \otimes_{O_K}M)$, where $K:=\text{Qout}(O_K)$ is the fraction field or quotient field of $O_K$, i.e.,
$r_2=\text{rank}_{O_K}(M)=\text{dim}_K(K \otimes_{O_K}M)=n$, say.

What about other ranks ?

Please help

Comment: Also at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390012/rank-of-a-module-m-over-the-rings-o-k-and-o-k-otimes-mathbbz-a). When crossposting, it's important to link all the versions of your question together to prevent duplicating work.

Comment: @KReiser, ok, I linked both